# Полученние введеного из формы и превращение его в переменную, после чего редирект. JS

Tags: php, javascript, авторизация

Есть такой код:

```
<?php
   $pass = isset($_POST['pass']) ? trim($_POST['pass']) : '';
   if($_GET["option"]=="password=pass"){
       echo "
            <div class='container'>
               <div class='title'>Привелегии</div>
               <div id='box-news'>
               <b>Скоро!</b>
            </div>
            </div>
       ";
   }
   else {
       echo "
            <div class='container'>
               <div class='title'>Привелегии</div>
               <div id='box-news'>
               <b>Не правильный пароль.</b>
            </div>
            </div>
       ";
   }
?>
```

Мне надо сделать форму, где одно поле: пароль, пользователь вводить туда информацию, жмет на кнопку. Js берет то что введено в поле и переводит на эту ссылку /nAdd.php?password=Тут то что ввел юзер. Искал, пока ничего не нашел.
Ничего проверять в джи-эс не надо, у меня сайт с подгрузкой контента, так что php если вдруг пароль не тот будет писать что он не правильный.

Это что-то типо авторизации.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-using-jquery

Comment: Это вообще не то, это я умею. Там есть какой-то длинный код, но я нуб в JS.

Answer (score 1):

Если необходимо чтобы форма отправлялась асинхронно, то ,как вариант, jquery ajax.
Примерно так:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: $(form).attr('action'), // либо можно явно '/nAdd.php'
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        type : 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data){
            // обрабатываете ответ
        }
    });
});
```

Если не асинхронно, то просто делаете форму на странице `<form action="/nAdd.php"/>` с полем